# Generate Twilio token with plain CURL/REST for IP Messaging and Programmable Video

Tags: twilio

I want to know how we can successfully initiate a Twilio Video call with a custom server that cannot use Twilio SDK like Node.js require.

Technically what is needed is to generate a Twilio token for IP Messaging and Programmable Video.

We have a Angular JS app + Custom Server that all it can do is REST/CURL, there's no documentation on Twilio website on how to generate the `token` with plain CURL/REST needed by a Javascript or Angular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You do not need curl or any HTTP requests to generate the access token for Twilio Video. The token is a JWT or JSON Web Token.

The Twilio documentation describes [the format of the JWTs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens) we use as an access token.

There are JWT libraries in most languages available, so you should be able to use one of them, if you are unable to use any Twilio libraries.

Comment: Thanks we will try this